# How can I select all user_ids and exclude some user ids in an ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created this controller and I need to exclude some user ids.

This is the controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = _context.sys_users.ToList();
    return View(users);
}
```

How to select all `user_ids` where `user_id not in (1, 2, 3)` ?

Comment: Look into LINQ.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior how to do it using LINQ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a list with the id to exclude and check when it does not exist in that list.

```
        int[] exclude = { 1, 2, 3 };
        var users = _context.sys_users.Where(m => !exclude.Contains(m.user_id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to filter the users.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var excludedUserIds = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 3 }; //or long whatever your IDs are
    var users = _context.sys_users.Where(u => !excludedUserIds.Contains(u.user_id)).ToListAsync(); // Use async methods whenever possible in IO methods such as DB access
    return View(users);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try the solution but I don't use async before